# Can I call function pointers directly?

Tags: c++, c

**The question I'm asking won't be used in production, it's pure curiosity**

---

Let's say I have a function, and its prototype is:

```
int myFunc(int, char*);
```

Supposing I know the static memory address (which is, for example, 0xC0DE), I can do this:

```
int (__cdecl* myFuncPtr)(int, char*) = (int(__cdecl*)(int, char*)) 0xC0DE;
myFuncPtr(1, "something");
```

Now, can I somehow call that function in one line, without the defining it? Like this:

```
((int(__cdecl*)) 0xC0DE)(1, "something");
```

Comment: Why do you suddenly change the cast to `int *`?

Comment: @chris Ups, that's my fault! Going to edit the post, thanks!

Comment: C++ and C are different languages. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Jefffrey I'm using whichever allows me to do what I'm trying, since this is a personal project and therefore, there's no requirements/limits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cast to a function pointer type instead of to `int*`:

```
((int(__cdecl*)(int, char const*)) 0xC0DE)(1, "something")
```

Note that this still invokes undefined behaviour and must be avoided unless your implementation explicitly documents you may do so and you don’t care about portability. If you want to be safe, at least use inline assembly so that you can rely on guarantees made by the target architecture, rather than by the compiler.

Comment: It's not any more or less undefined than the 2-liner than it replaces, though.

Comment: @Barmar: That's what *still* means.

Comment: @FredLarson: Both were, however, crucial ingredients at the meeting at which it was decided that `((int(__cdecl*)(int, char const*)) 0xC0DE)` should be legitimate syntax.

Answer (score 4):

In C, but not C++, you can omit the argument types:

```
((int(*)()) 0xC0DE)(1, "something");
```

Comment: In C++ and C, you can do `((int (__cdecl*)(...)) 0xC0DE)(2, "something else")`, provided your compiler define `__cdecl`. But that's even less type safety, and possibly more undefined behavior involved.

Comment: @BenVoigt You can only omit the arguments types if the arguments match their type after the default argument promotions (which they do in this case). However, omitting the `__cdecl` may break it (if the default calling convention was something else)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: What C compiler supports `__cdecl`?  It's a Microsoft-specific keyword available in their C++ compiler...

Comment: C compilers have support for different calling conventions. It wasn't stated that MSVC is in use here

Comment: @MattMcNabb: But then you would need one of the keywords specific to that C compiler, not a MS C++ non-portable keyword.

Comment: Maybe that compiler has __cdecl, or OP's code has `#define __cdecl` to whatever token his compiler uses

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Do you know if a prototyped function's type (if it is a type only accepting arguments of fully-promoted types) is compatible with any non-prototyped (but declared) function's type? (IIRC they aren't, but I'm not sure currently).

Comment: @mafso only if the argument types are unchanged after applying the *default argument promotions* (C99 6.5.2.2)